# Save application state with multiple forms

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have an application with multiple forms (10-15 different forms), and I have to save the state of the application when exiting, meaning in the next bootup I have to restore the last opened form with the proper data loaded in.

Based on my research so far I can do this using serialization. I can save the data for each form, and when loading back up I can populate the forms. 
My problem is that I have to communicate between the forms using the DialogResult property. For example:

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
if(form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes){
    //do some stuff
}
else {
    //do some other stuff
}
```

How can I program that the newly created Form2 returns to Form1 after deserialization?

Comment: It seems simple enough to to save as part of your state the fact that you are displaying a dialog and redisplay as part of a home-grown "OnRestore" event.  But are you saying you have 15 modal dialogs all stacked up?

Comment: @tcarvin I have 15 different possible forms in the application. Not all of them  are open at the same time, the maximum is maybe 7. It is kinda like a linked list, where from form 1 I open form 2, from there I open form3, and so on. So when i restore the program from the xml, and it displays form3 for example, when i close it form2 should display, since that is the only place form3 is called.

Comment: Do you use ShowDialog to display *all* the forms?  And do you really have the ability to exit the app from every screen?

Comment: @tcarvin yes, I use ShowDialog everywhere. This backup functionality is required mainly because the app is going to run on a PDA, and I have to ensure that no data is in case the device runs out of power.
Now that I think it through more I have a fundamental design flaw. I do all the functionality on the forms, rather than in separate classes. If I fix that, than this serialization problem is going to sort itself out. Thank you for your answers, Cheers